# How to make Windows ask for credentials on network shared folder every time

Tags: windows, networking, credentials-manager

We have a Windows machine accesible online via remote desktop. It has an admin user that is only a local one, outside the domain of a specific network shared folder.

Several operators make use of this machine. They log in via the same admin user. Then, when they need to access the shared folder, they are requested for their own personal credentials in the domain of the network shared folders, which they have.

So far so good. The problem is that, when another operator logs into the machine via the admin user, the personal credentials for the domain folders are still stored, so the operator can "impersonate" another operator (they have the same rights in the machine because they use the admin user, but they have different rights in the network folders).

Is there a way to ensure **the credentials are not stored and requested every time the folder is accessed** (or with a very **short timeout**)? Is this configurable **on the side of the machine accessing the folders** (e.g. in the windows credentials manager), or on the side of the machine hosting the network folders?

Comment: You could likely write a script, when the administrator user logs out, and clear the stored credentials.

Comment: "They log in via the same admin user." - Don't. Set up a separate user on the machine for each user who is allowed access, and change the admin password.